# How to access the floating ip in browser rather than a localhost?

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, socket, openstack, ip-forwarding

I have an instances that was made in OpenStack which have a floating IP for its instance, the IP for this machine is `10.1.1.164`. I tried to forward this instances so it  will accessible in my firefox browser locally. First i used this ssh `command` to connect to the system

```
ssh -L 8080:10.1.1.164:80 myuser@iptomyremotemachine -p 2212
```

and than i setting my firefox socket to listen to port 8080 like this.
 [image]

This is works fine but only if i used `localhost:8080` and failed if i use `10.1.1.164:8080`. I expect i could used floating ip rather than localhost. What's wrong with my ssh command ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your instance does not know about the floating IP address. It will route the traffic to that IP address through it's gateway, where the OpenStack Security Groups apply. If you want to connect to your instance through the floating IP (regardless if you do it through the SSH tunnel or directly) you will have to open the port in a Security Group for your instance.

If you want to connect through the SSH tunnel you have to terminate it at the **private** IP address of your instance:

```
ssh -L 8080:192.168.0.X:80 myuser@iptomyremotemachine -p 2212
```